# Why is there an abandoned village in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

I'm playing Minecraft ED v1.14.50 with seed 209342195.

I found an abandoned village near where I spawned. There was no traces of an attack or whatever.

The villagers are just gone.

Does anyone know what happened to the village?

[image: No villagers?]

Comment: This is an intentional possibility to be generated

Comment: @RayWu really? Usually that's just 'cause they all die the first night, I've never seen or heard of that

Comment: This was empty the moment I spawned... @RayWu

Answer (score 2):

Abandoned village is a naturally spawning village type. There are no villagers (and there may be zombie villagers ) and the fields will have water overflowing. The houses may be broken too. Its usually a big mess and i recommend taking everything useful and then leaving it behind. ( I tried to repair the village and set up my home in one but its just not worth the effort, i would rather find an actual village due to the many perks of villagers )

The wiki page for abandoned villages is [here](https://minecraft-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Abandoned_Village)

Answer (score 1):

It probably is just an abandoned village because in an abandoned desert village there isn't any visual signs that the village is abandoned.